# Possible to inject resource files into .net assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, resources, decompiling, reflector

There's a .net program for students that I've been messing around with in Reflector and Reflexil, but it doesn't look like they can work with resource files. I want to replace the default background with a custom one. How feasible is this?

I've tried exporting the assembly as a C# project and maybe rebuilding with the resource files swapped, but a few classes won't decompile right when exporting and crashes Reflector when I try to view the full source code inside reflector (after clicking 'expand methods')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of applicaiton is it? WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, Web?  You can do it with ILDasm round triping.  If you let me know what type of app it is I'll post the steps you need to take.

Comment: It's a ClickOnce application (WinForms I guess?)

Comment: ildasm round tripping worked!
disassembled the exe, the resource files were right there to be messed around with, reassembled with ilasm

Comment: Cool, sorry yesterday was a busy day and I never got a chance to check back.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Reflexil 1.3 is now able to handle resources.

Answer (score 0):

Quite difficult, probably Hex Editor can help.

Answer (score 0):

Resource Hacker can do it. Follow; **Action > Add a new Resource**

[delphi.icm.edu.pl/ftp/tools/ResHack.zip](http://delphi.icm.edu.pl/ftp/tools/ResHack.zip)

Comment: I'm only able to see the icon files but no other resource files. Am I using it wrong or does it only edit icons?

Answer (score 0):

I just put out GrayWolf to edit programs, I don't have the ability to edit resource(s) (if you donate$:) yet

but I would think the easy change is to edit the program to load the background from disk (./back1.jpg)

I have others tools that would make it easy to change the background of the running program see
"Hacking .NET" at DefCon18

other tools "GrayDragon"
I have a payload that does just this, it is for DefCon19, but if you send me an e-mail...

Happy hunting